# power steering/hydraulic cylinder hose replacement - '95 JD 425

Tags: power-steering, hose, john-deere

I am attempting to replace a leaky connection between one of the two hoses running from my tractor's power steering cylinder.  I was able to remove one of the hoses (assuming inbound), but I was not able to remove the 2nd hose (assuming return) which is harder to reach under the tractor.

The nut can be turned but there is so much tension on the hose it simply reverts back to the same position as soon as I remove the wrench. I am very new to this - just bought the tractor and got this problem immediately. My goal is to replace the O-rings without having to take apart the whole power steering system. Any recommendations about how to remove this hose and reattach? Thanks

[image: pic two]
[image: pic one]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one of two ways to overcome your conundrum:

1. Remove the hose at the other end. This will allow you to turn the entire thing and remove the hose completely.
2. Remove the hydraulic cylinder and turn it around until the hose disconnects.

By far, the easier of the two solutions should be #1.